# Handling calculator input via strings VS. arithmetic

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm creating a GUI application which has an input in form of a calculator keyboard (very similar to your standard iOS or Android calculator app). The common input flow we all familiar with is to append each new digit to the end of a currently displayed number.

From the perspective of both error safety and performance, is it better to concatenate a new digit to the end of an existing string and parse it when a new operation is to be performed — or to represent the number as a float or a double from the beginning?

Nowadays all the tutorials that I see on the topic are suggesting the string approach. Just intuitively, calculators are about numbers, not strings, so I'm hesitating to use this approach right now; however, I can't really find any strong reason against it, since it is much simpler to implement than tracking the significant and the exponent of a number.

This being said, I'm pretty sure that the actual calculators are not using strings. If anyone could describe me how they handle their inputs, I'd be very thankful.

Also, I'm worried that using floating point numbers for input could affect precision — but I'm not sure here either. Would be glad to hear as many opinions as possible. I'm writing the app in Swift, but the same question could apply to a similar app in JavaScript or Kotlin, for example.